# UWP XAML NavigationMenu Change behavior

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-navigation

I'm using NavigationView in a UWP project that contains a Frame to load pages.

When the windows is small enough the NavigationView Pane is automatically closed only showing the Icons of the MenuItems, if the Menu is specifically opened (clicking the top button) the menu overlaps the pages inside the frame (this happens after a given threshold, when the Window becomes smaller)

I was trying to maintain this behavior all the time (instead of only when the window is resized to small values), even if the window is maximized or is resized to large values.

isPaneOpen appears to be a read only property that does not work at Run time.
The overlap (rather than pushing the frame to the right) I don't know how to get this NavigationView display all the time...

Any  help how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it absolutely essential for you to implement it using `NavigationView` ? Because you can implement the same functionality and fulfill your requirement of having the   overlap side menu using `SplitView`..

Answer (score 0):

As your description, it seems you want to maintain the [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#navigationview-display-modes) always in the **Compact** mode, you can implement this effect by overriding the widths at which the navigation view changes display modes using the `CompactModeThresholdWidth` and `ExpandedModeThresholdWidth` properties.

You can try to configure your `NavigationView` as the following code,

```
<NavigationView CompactModeThresholdWidth="280" ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="2000"/>
```

You can set any `CompactModeThresholdWidth` property value smaller than the minimum default UWP app window width and the `ExpandedModeThresholdWidth` property value larger than the maximum window width.

More details, please see the [NavigationView display modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#navigationview-display-modes) topic.